# Ubuntu is freezing

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, partitioning, gparted, swap

I was running a dual boot of windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04. my Ubuntu was running out of disk space and I decided to go to windows and resize the Ubuntu partition to a larger volume but realized it was not possible

after reading different online articles on how to resize partitions in Ubuntu, i decided to use the live cd method and opened `gparted` then resized my Ubuntu partition though i was unsuccessful at the start because I had never done it before.

i managed to later increase the space of the Ubuntu disk though in the process, I deleted the windows partition but kinda didnt bother a lot since I was planning on uninstalling windows soon. i resized the ubuntu partition and thought that was all. there was no space i left unallocated because i shared the volume between the ubuntu partition and local disk.

when i restarted my PC, i realized after some time that it had started hanging and decided to go increase the swap partition from 3.5gb to 8gb (since i read somewhere that the swap partition is supposed to be twice your RAM. and my laptop got 4gb ram), because i thought maybe the problem was with the swap memory.

after restarting into my Ubuntu, i thought i was set and to realize, freezing became intense because my laptop has been freezing for the whole day. it never used to freeze a lot when i had windows(would freeze but once in a while). so i am so confused now and don't know what to do because theres even a downloader of mine that just canceled all my running downloads with an error saying "Your computer does not have enough free memory"

Comment: any help will be appreciated

Comment: Unless you have a really hard to replicated setup, i'd just reinstall ubuntu on my entire hdd.

Comment: I agree with smurfendrek123.  You've already removed windows and your *NIX distro is apparently not running very well.  The quickest way to resolve this would be to do a clean Ubuntu install.  Since you seem rather unfamiliar with Linux you should probably take the recommended defaults on installation and the read up on how to improve performance.  Not also that 4 GB RAM is going to give pretty poor performance.

Comment: jones0610, how exactly can i install a fresh ubuntu distro? like should i delete the ubuntu partition first or something? because i really have a lot of software installed and would want to do this installation once and for all. i have over neshed with program installation for so long and want to do it one more time alone not now and again. so, throw me some light on how to do a clean installation.

Comment: or cant i install it in a way to retain my current programs and just do a little repair?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)

Comment: @MrCyber you just plug in a live usb stick with ubuntu on it and choose the option to erase disk and install ubuntu, that leaves nothing to go wrong and nothing to worry about. Make sure to back up your files first because this really will erase everything.

Comment: Do you change/etc/ fstab uuid's after changing swap partition and root partition ?

Comment: the freezing is becoming minimal as of now and i am reconsidering keeping the Ubuntu. but thanks guys for the help yall showed.